# Error when getting a transaction using Netsuite Ruby Gem - Savon::SOAPFault: (soapenv:Server.userException)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, savon, netsuite

I'm using the netsuite ruby gem (https://github.com/RevolutionPrep/netsuite).

I talked to the founder of the gem and I'm using the correct way of grabbing a transaction:
https://github.com/RevolutionPrep/netsuite/issues/52

In Gemfile:

```
gem 'netsuite'
```

I keep getting this when doing the transaction search:

```
1.9.3p448 :008 > search = NetSuite::Records::Transaction.get(3820)
HTTPI GET request to webservices.netsuite.com (net_http)
HTTPI POST request to webservices.netsuite.com (net_http)
Savon::SOAPFault: (soapenv:Server.userException) org.xml.sax.SAXException: transaction is not a legal value for {urn:types.core_2013_2.platform.webservices.netsuite.com}RecordType
```

This gives the same error as well:

```
search = NetSuite::Records::Transaction.get(:internal_id => 3820)
```

This works:

```
def getAllTransactions
    #SearchStringField, searchValue

    t = Time.new 

    search = NetSuite::Records::Transaction.search({
        criteria: {
        basic: [
            {
                field: 'type',
                operator: 'anyOf',
                type: 'SearchEnumMultiSelectField',
                value: [ "_invoice" ]
            },
            {
                field: 'tranDate',
                operator: 'within',

                type: 'SearchDateField',
                value: [
                      Date.parse("12/1/2013").strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z"),
                      Date.parse("#{t.month}/#{t.day}/#{t.year}").strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z")
                    ]
            }
            ]
        }
    })

    search
end
```

And this works too:

```
NetSuite::Records::Customer.get(:internal_id => 3820)
```

These don't work:

```
1.9.3p448 :007 > customer = NetSuite::Records::Invoice.get(:internal_id => 7996) 
HTTPI GET request to webservices.netsuite.com (net_http)
HTTPI POST request to webservices.netsuite.com (net_http)
NetSuite::RecordNotFound: NetSuite::Records::Invoice with OPTIONS={:internal_id=>7996} could not be found
    from /Users/pkatepalli/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/netsuite-0.2.0/lib/netsuite/actions/get.rb:73:in `get'
    from (irb):7
    from /Users/pkatepalli/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
    from /Users/pkatepalli/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
    from /Users/pkatepalli/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:5:in `require'
    from script/rails:5:in `<main>'

1.9.3p448 :008 > customer = NetSuite::Records::SalesOrder.get(:internal_id => 7996)
HTTPI GET request to webservices.netsuite.com (net_http)
HTTPI POST request to webservices.netsuite.com (net_http)
NetSuite::RecordNotFound: NetSuite::Records::SalesOrder with OPTIONS={:internal_id=>7996} could not be found
    from /Users/pkatepalli/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/netsuite-0.2.0/lib/netsuite/actions/get.rb:73:in `get'
    from (irb):8
    from /Users/pkatepalli/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
    from /Users/pkatepalli/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
    from /Users/pkatepalli/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:5:in `require'
    from script/rails:5:in `<main>'

1.9.3p448 :009 > customer = NetSuite::Records::CashSale.get(:internal_id => 7996)
HTTPI GET request to webservices.netsuite.com (net_http)
HTTPI POST request to webservices.netsuite.com (net_http)
NetSuite::RecordNotFound: NetSuite::Records::CashSale with OPTIONS={:internal_id=>7996} could not be found
    from /Users/pkatepalli/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/netsuite-0.2.0/lib/netsuite/actions/get.rb:73:in `get'
    from (irb):9
    from /Users/pkatepalli/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:47:in `start'
    from /Users/pkatepalli/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:8:in `start'
    from /Users/pkatepalli/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/railties-3.2.12/lib/rails/commands.rb:41:in `<top (required)>'
    from script/rails:5:in `require'
    from script/rails:5:in `<main>'
```

this works:

```
1.9.3p448 :010 > customer = NetSuite::Records::Customer.get(:internal_id => 7996)
HTTPI GET request to webservices.netsuite.com (net_http)
HTTPI POST request to webservices.netsuite.com (net_http)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't pull a Transaction record – you have to pull a specific *type* or transaction record. Some types include: Invoice, SalesOrder, and CashSale.

Try going to the following url:

https://system.netsuite.com/app/accounting/transactions/transaction.nl?id=3820

This should give you an idea of what transaction type the record is. If it's an Invoice, you would retrieve it using:

```
NetSuite::Records::Invoice.get(1234)
```

---

Here are some rough notes on the NS transaction flow. Some of it might be specific to our instance, but the majority of it applies to NS as a whole and might be helpful to you or others trying to piece together how NS works.

- most of the time every CashSale (CS) and invoice, has a sales order (SO) associated with it. In the case of a recurring charge (like a monthly service fee) a CS or invoice does not have to have a SO associated with it
- a SO can either have a sales paid order or an invoice associated with it. Ex: if someone paid on the spot with a CC, then it generates a "Cash Sale"
- a SO, CS order, and invoice all have similar data but all have unique NS IDs. They aren't different views of the same data ala Contact vs Customer view on the same NS ID.
- a SO will never progress past the "billed" state even after a full payment has been made
- transactions are a flow. each record represents something semantically. therefore, in the normal flow of business, one might be generated as a consequense of another. so, a Sales Order means, a sales person was on the phone with a person and they ordered something if the company will pay for it later then when it gets "Billed" that generates an Invoice, which is a statement requesting payment for goods/services

Comment: hey thank you so much for this explanation but I'm still having trouble. I have the list of invoices in netsuite showing up. And I'm able to use the internal id to get the customer, but that same internal id doesn't work to get the invoice, sales order or cash sale, and that specific internal id is in the url of the invoice when I go to it.

Comment: A sales order, invoice, and cash sale will all have separate internal IDs. You cannot use the same internal ID to access all of those records.

Comment: Got you. Is there a way to do a transaction search and join it to a customer by the customer's internal id?

Comment: Most likely – not 100% sure off the top of my head. Check our the NS WSDL and the documentation on the GH page for examples on how to do a join search https://github.com/RevolutionPrep/netsuite

Comment: cool. I tried this and got a soap error: (soapenv:Server.userException) org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Element or attribute do not match QName production: QName::=(NCName':')?NCName. Any ideas on how I should change this?

   @search = NetSuite::Records::Transaction.search({
    criteria: {
    basic: [
     {
      field: 'type',
      operator: 'anyOf',
      type: 'SearchEnumMultiSelectField',
      value: [ "_invoice" ]
     },
    customerJoin: [
      {
        field: 'internalId',
        operator: 'is',
        value: [ 7996 ]
      }
    ]
    ]
   }
   })

Comment: I am also getting Savon::SOAPFault: (soapenv:Server.userException) org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Element or attribute do not match QName production: QName::=(NCName':')?NCName

Answer (score 3):

When the NS gem generates the SOAP XML, it is, in fact, adding an incorrect type:

```
<env:Body>
  <platformMsgs:get>
    <platformMsgs:baseRef xsi:type="platformCore:RecordRef" internalId="130619" type="transaction"/>
  </platformMsgs:get>
</env:Body>
```

type='transaction' is being correctly reported as an error. When you look at the [Schema Browser](https://system.netsuite.com/help/helpcenter/en_US/SchemaBrowser/indexv2013_2_0.html), you can click the '[types]' in the top left frame for 'platform core.xsd'. Then click the link for 'RecordType' that appears in the lower left frame.

After clicking RecordType, a list of RecordTypes appears in the right frame. As you scroll through this list, you will see that it does not contain an entry for 'transaction'.

However, the `NetSuite::Records::Transaction` class appears to be nothing more than a wrapper for the `SalesOrder` class.

When I ran the following in a console, all transaction (i.e., sales) data was returned in a `SalesOrder` object:

```
NetSuite::Records::SalesOrder.get(interal_id: 1234)
```

Long story short, if you need to just grab a single transaction (versus searching transactions, which you note does work), would your app and requirements allow you to just use the `SalesOrder` class instead?

Comment: Hey Craig, I get this when I do that: NetSuite::RecordNotFound: NetSuite::Records::SalesOrder with OPTIONS={:internal_id=>3820} could not be found

Comment: Not to ask an overly stupid question but can you verify, in NetSuite, that a sales transaction exists with an internal_id of 3820? When I ran my test, I went to NS first, snagged an ID and then plugged that into the console. Because that error you got is raised within a begin - rescue - end block, it might also be worth checking your netsuite.log file and see what was sent to and returned from NetSuite. I've had some of my best luck getting around NS issues with the log file.

Comment: Hey Craig, There's an invoice with an internal_id of 3820. I double checked.